# SSL Error on upgrade to WSO2 IS 5.1 with apache http server

Tags: apache, httpserver, wso2-identity-server

We are in process of upgrading WSO2 IS 5.0 SP1 to WSo2 5.1. The communication with WSO2 IS happens via a Apache HTTP server 2.2. This Communication works fine with WSO2 IS 5.0 SP1. But when we upgrade to 5.1 we get the following error message on the browser.

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server could not handle the request GET /services/EntitlementService.
Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server
```

**Update:**

On inspecting the apache log we get the following error

```
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1974): proxy: HTTP: serving URL https://[IP]:9443/services/EntitlementService?wsdl
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(2018): proxy: HTTPS: has acquired connection for ([IP])
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(2074): proxy: connecting https://[IP]:9443/services/EntitlementService?wsdl to [IP]:9443
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(2200): proxy: connected /services/EntitlementService?wsdl to [IP]:9443
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(2451): proxy: HTTPS: fam 2 socket created to connect to [IP]
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(2583): proxy: HTTPS: connection complete to [IP]:9443 ([IP])
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [info] [client [IP]] Connection to child 0 established (server [HOSTNAME]:443)
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [info] Seeding PRNG with 136 bytes of entropy
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1871): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1879): OpenSSL: Loop: before/connect initialization
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1879): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1947): OpenSSL: I/O error, 7 bytes expected to read on BIO#33bb678 [mem: a59cd0]
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1908): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [info] [client [IP]] SSL Proxy connect failed
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [info] [client [IP]] Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server [HOSTNAME]:443)
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [error] (502)Unknown error: proxy: pass request body failed to [IP]:9443 ([IP])
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [error] [client [IP]] proxy: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /services/EntitlementService
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to [IP]:9443 ([IP]) from [IP] ()
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(2036): proxy: HTTPS: has released connection for ([IP])
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1889): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Fri Jan 29 11:34:59 2016] [info] [client [IP]] Connection closed to child 63 with standard shutdown (server [HOSTNAME]:443)
```

Kindly advice.

Comment: Are you going to use Apache HTTP server as reverse proxy ?

Comment: Yes we are using Apache HTTP server as reverse proxy